# Gelfand vs Parasonson pure math textbook for pre calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, book-recommendation

I own all four books from Gelfand’s series and Parasonson’s volume 1 pure math book. I was going to read Gelfand’s algebra first, but I’m curious if reading Parasonon’s volume one, at least up to the trigonometry section, will be enough alone to cover precalculus subjects such as the algebra and trigonometry I will need. My goal is to get to Spivak or Courant so that’s why I’m considering these two rigorous options instead of a precalculus text.

Wondering if anyone has experience with either the Gelfand series or Parasonson.

Answer (score 1):

Math books are not like fiction novels: you can read two books at the same time. In fact it is usually the preferred method to study math.